# How/when does Angular/PrimeNG rename the CSS classes from 'p-' to 'ui-'?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I have a pretty dumb problem. I have created a custom PrimeNG component, which appears to be working fine, however there are 2 issues:

- Even if I use ViewEncapsulation.None just like other PrimeNG components, the used / existing PrimeNG CSS classes (e.g. p-datepicker styles from PrimeNG's theme files) are not applied to my component. Obviously if I copy-paste the corresponding styles to my coponent's scss file they work just fine
- I have absolutely no idea who/when/how renames the name of the CSS classes from 'p-*' to 'ui-*'. The issue is that the renaming doesn't happen for my custom PrimeNG component, they remain prefixed by 'p-', so obviously the component is not properly styled.

If I think it over I guess the root cause of the first issue the very same (the component should be using ui-datepicker, however it uses p-datepicker still, which is not available).

Anyone has any idea?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Meh :( There is no auto renaming at all. The confusion came from the fact that I was creating my component based upon the github sources, and my app was including an older primeng version obviously, and indeed since then PrimeNG decided to remove the CSS classes from ui- to p-